# Query Different Condition With 1 Column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table like :

```
+-------+--------+----------+------------+-------+
| cd_hs | cd_cnt | name_cnt |   dates    | value |
+-------+--------+----------+------------+-------+
|     1 |      1 | aaa      | 2018-06-01 |    50 |
|     1 |      2 | bbb      | 2018-07-01 |   150 |
|     1 |      3 | ccc      | 2018-08-01 |    20 |
|     1 |      1 | aaa      | 2018-06-02 |    40 |
|     1 |      2 | bbb      | 2018-07-02 |    70 |
|     1 |      3 | ccc      | 2018-08-02 |    80 |
+-------+--------+----------+------------+-------+
```

Actually I have more data but I am just show the sample and what I want to do is

I want to group by `cd_hs`, `name_cnt` and based on `year` in `dates` column and do `sum(value)` but I have the 2 condition. First is to show value with condition `cd_cnt with 1 and 2` and second condition `cd_cnt without 1 and 2` so meaning I have much value other than 1 and 2 and do aliasing as `other` in one column

Expected Result :

```
+-------+------+----------+-------------+
| cd_hs | year | name_cnt | total_value |
+-------+------+----------+-------------+
|     1 | 2018 | aaa      |          90 |
|     1 | 2018 | bbb      |         220 |
|     1 | 2018 | other    |         100 |
+-------+------+----------+-------------+
```

how can I do that? I am new in query and don't know what to do..

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit confusing considering your spec doesn't seem to exactly line up with what you requested.

If the sample result you've provided is ***actually*** what you're looking for, a simple `SUM` and `GROUP BY` should do the trick here:

```
SELECT cd_hs, EXTRACT(YEAR from dates) as year, name_cnt, SUM(value_)
FROM foo
GROUP BY cd_hs, EXTRACT(YEAR from dates), name_cnt
```

Result:

```
| cd_hs | year | name_cnt | sum |
|-------|------|----------|-----|
|     1 | 2018 |      aaa |  90 |
|     1 | 2018 |      bbb | 220 |
|     1 | 2018 |      ccc | 100 |
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ebaf5/8)

---

Since you mentioned you wanted two different totals with two separate conditions, you could use `JOIN` in conjunction with some well-crafted subqueries:

```
SELECT a.cd_hs, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM a.dates), a.name_cnt, COALESCE(b.total_a, 0) as "Total A", COALESCE(c.total_b, 0) as "Total B"
FROM foo a
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT b.cd_hs, b.name_cnt, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM b.dates), SUM(value_) as total_a
  FROM foo b
  WHERE b.cd_cnt NOT IN (1, 2)
  GROUP BY b.cd_hs, b.name_cnt, EXTRACT(YEAR from b.dates)
) b ON a.cd_hs = b.cd_hs AND a.name_cnt = b.name_cnt
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT c.cd_hs, c.name_cnt, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM c.dates), SUM(value_) as total_b
  FROM foo c
  WHERE c.cd_cnt IN (1, 2)
  GROUP BY c.cd_hs, c.name_cnt, EXTRACT(YEAR from c.dates)
) c ON a.cd_hs = c.cd_hs AND a.name_cnt = c.name_cnt
```

This particular solution is readable and will get you to the correct end result but will most likely not be scalable in its current form.

Result:

```
| cd_hs | date_part | name_cnt | Total A | Total B |
|-------|-----------|----------|---------|---------|
|     1 |      2018 |      aaa |       0 |      90 |
|     1 |      2018 |      bbb |       0 |     220 |
|     1 |      2018 |      ccc |     100 |       0 |
|     1 |      2018 |      aaa |       0 |      90 |
|     1 |      2018 |      bbb |       0 |     220 |
|     1 |      2018 |      ccc |     100 |       0 |
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ebaf5/7)